# Microsoft Exchange

Tags: email, smtp, outlook, exchangewebservices

Tengo una duda con el **Microsoft Exchange Server 2010**, estuve buscando por Internet si el servidor puede mandar correos automáticamente, como por ejemplo, que mande a todos los usuarios un correo diciendo a la hora que se realiza un `backup` diariamente.

¿Se puede hacer o necesito un programa externo del Exchange para poder hacerlo?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: hace falta más información... pero antes de hacer el backup, si lo haces con servidor linux, puedes hacer un crontab que envíe el mail al iniciar y al finalizar, por ejemplo. Si pretendes hacerlo automáticamente desde Exchange, es otro tema, hay una opción si mal no recuerdo

Comment: Esque estoy buscando en los registros diarios y solo veo la función de capturar todos los transportes, pero no encuentro uno que envie correos.